# Cannot find definitions of tx___ functions in English Auction script

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground

I might be missing some thing but in the English Auction script I am unable to find the definitions of the function that starts with tx:

```
txOutDatumHash  
txInInfoResolved
txOutValue 
txInInfoResolved
...
```

Does anyone know where these functions are defined?

Answer (score 2):

Since they're not defined directly in EnglishAuction.hs, they must be imported from somewhere else. You can see all the imports starting on line 32.

The haddock docs for Plutus can give some more information. Look at [the index for the letter "T"](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/doc-index-T.html)  and scroll down until you start seeing things that start with "tx".

For example, `txOutDatumHash` and `txOutValue` are part of the [constructor for the `TxOut` datatype](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V2-Ledger-Api.html#t:TxOut).

Comment: Thanks. that answers other questions I have regarding the script.